# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while reading file and trying to plot the values

Tags: python, regression, correlation

## loading data from file

```
my_data=pd.read_excel('DailyVanSale.xlsx',delimiter=',')
```

## converting into matrix format

```
data=my_data.as_matrix()
productid=data[:10,1]
```

## converting to float type

```
productid.astype('float')
sales=data[:10,7]
sales.astype('float')
print(type(sales))
print(type(productid))
```

## Corelation and regression

```
func=lambda m,x,c:float(m)*float(x)+float(c)
vf=sp.vectorize(func)
popt,pcov=spo.curve_fit(func,productid,sales)
```

## Plotting

```
yc=vf(popt[0],productid,popt[1])
```

## Label in the graph

```
plt.plot(productid,sales,'r:o',label='observed')
plt.plot(productid,yc,'b-v',label='calculated')
```

## legend in plot

```
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 18, in <module>
    popt,pcov=spo.curve_fit(func,productid,sales)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 751, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 383, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 27, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/opt/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 463, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "project.py", line 16, in <lambda>
    func=lambda m,x,c:float(m)*float(x)+float(c)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

`productid.astype('float')`

This is not an in-place operation. At this point, you have not cast `productid` to `float`.

`sales.astype('float')`

Same here.

`func=lambda m,x,c:float(m)*float(x)+float(c)`

`TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

I would believe that at least one of the values passed to m, x, or c have higher dimensions than (1, 1).